# How to implement One Tap Login in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api

I'm trying to implement Google One Tap Login on our Magento 2 site and I have followed the below guide but not sure where can I start

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web
[image]

Please help me to implement the One Tap Login on my website.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: HI Script , Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Did you check? https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-one-tap-login.html

Comment: @purnagattu not yet did you got any solution from your side.

Comment: @GauravJain thanks for the info regarding the plugin, but our client doesn't allow plugin, is there any solution creating a custom model via the method.

Comment: @GauravJain we need a solution for Enterprise Edition, the plugin is for the community alone.

Comment: @ScriptHost It's available for Commerce/Enterprise/Cloud Edition too, please check http://prntscr.com/uhn31g